# what is the printer commands used for TVS LP 45 barcode printer in java?

Tags: java, printing

What are the printer commands used for `TVS LP 45` barcode printer ? We used `TSCLIB.dll` file to get our java project to print , but it doesn't print ? What is the actual barcode printer commands used to print `TVS LP 45` ?

Comment: You should probably contact tech support of the manufacturer and a developer's manual for this product. Otherwise, post the source code of your attempt to print.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Manos. It prints good using EPL commands and emulation used for TVS LP 45 is : BPLE.

Comment: @Anands23: I am also looking for such manual? Can you plz share if you have already collected?

Answer (score 0):

Some months ago i worked with LP 45 label printer. I used the regular Java code for printing.

```
package default;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
/**
 *
 * @author All Open source developers
 * @version 1.0.0.0
 * @since 2014/12/22
 */
/*This Printsupport java class was implemented to get printout.
* This class was specially designed to print a Jtable content to a paper.
* Specially this class formated to print 7cm width paper.
* Generally for pos thermel printer.
* Free to customize this source code as you want.
* Illustration of basic invoice is in this code.
* demo by gayan liyanaarachchi

 */

public class Printsupport {

         static JTable itemsTable;
         public static  int total_item_count=0;
         public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a";
         public  static String title[] = new String[] {"Item ID","Item Name","Price","Quantity"};

public static void setItems(Object[][] printitem){
        Object data[][]=printitem;
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
       //assume jtable has 4 columns.
        model.addColumn(title[0]);
        model.addColumn(title[1]);
        model.addColumn(title[2]);
        model.addColumn(title[3]);


        int rowcount=printitem.length;

        addtomodel(model, data, rowcount);


        itemsTable = new JTable(model);
}

public static void addtomodel(DefaultTableModel model,Object [][]data,int rowcount){
        int count=0;
        while(count < rowcount){
         model.addRow(data[count]);
         count++;
        }
        if(model.getRowCount()!=rowcount)
          addtomodel(model, data, rowcount);

        System.out.println("Check Passed.");
}

public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    int itemcount=table.getRowCount();
    System.out.println("Item Count:"+itemcount);

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol =dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    if(itemcount==nRow)                                        //check is there any data loss.
    {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++){
            tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);           //pass data into object array.
            }}
     if(tableData.length!=itemcount){                      //check for data losses in object array
     getTableData(table);                                  //recursively call method back to collect data
     }   
    System.out.println("Data check passed");
    }
    else{
                                                           //collecting data again because of data loss.
   getTableData(table);
   }
   return tableData;                                       //return object array with data.
    }     

public static PageFormat getPageFormat(PrinterJob pj){
        PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
        Paper paper = pf.getPaper();    

                double middleHeight =total_item_count*1.0;  //dynamic----->change with the row count of jtable
                double headerHeight = 5.0;                  //fixed----->but can be mod
            double footerHeight = 5.0;                  //fixed----->but can be mod

                double width = convert_CM_To_PPI(7);      //printer know only point per inch.default value is 72ppi
            double height = convert_CM_To_PPI(headerHeight+middleHeight+footerHeight); 
            paper.setSize(width, height);
            paper.setImageableArea(
                            convert_CM_To_PPI(0.25), 
                            convert_CM_To_PPI(0.5), 
                            width - convert_CM_To_PPI(0.35), 
                            height - convert_CM_To_PPI(1));   //define boarder size    after that print area width is about 180 points

            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);           //select orientation portrait or landscape but for this time portrait
            pf.setPaper(paper);    

            return pf;
}


protected static double convert_CM_To_PPI(double cm) {            
            return toPPI(cm * 0.393600787);            
}

protected static double toPPI(double inch) {            
            return inch * 72d;            
}

public static String now() {
//get current date and time as a String output   
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

}

public static class MyPrintable implements Printable {
 @Override
  public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, 
                    int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {    
                    int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;    
                    if (pageIndex == 0) {                    
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;                    

                    double width = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
                    double height = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();    
                    g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),(int) pageFormat.getImageableY()); 
                    Font font = new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,7);       
                    g2d.setFont(font);


                    try {
                /*
                         * Draw Image*
                           assume that printing reciept has logo on top 
                         * that logo image is in .gif format .png also support
                         * image resolution is width 100px and height 50px
                         * image located in root--->image folder 
                         */
                                    int x=100 ;                                        //print start at 100 on x axies
                                    int y=10;                                          //print start at 10 on y axies
                                    int imagewidth=100;
                                    int imageheight=50;
                          BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image/logo.gif"));
                          g2d.drawImage(read,x,y,imagewidth,imageheight,null);         //draw image
                          g2d.drawLine(10, y+60, 180, y+60);                          //draw line
                                 } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            try{
            /*Draw Header*/
                    int y=80;
                  g2d.drawString("ABC Shopping Complex", 40,y);  
                  g2d.drawString("CopyWrite 2009-2014", 50,y+10);                 //shift a line by adding 10 to y value
                  g2d.drawString(now(), 10, y+20);                                //print date
                  g2d.drawString("Cashier : admin", 10, y+30);  

                  /*Draw Colums*/
                      g2d.drawLine(10, y+40, 180, y+40);
                      g2d.drawString(title[0], 10 ,y+50);
                      g2d.drawString(title[1], 50 ,y+50);
                      g2d.drawString(title[2], 100 ,y+50);
                      g2d.drawString(title[3], 150 ,y+50);
                      g2d.drawLine(10, y+60, 180, y+60);

                  int cH = 0;
                  TableModel mod = itemsTable.getModel();

                  for(int i = 0;i < mod.getRowCount() ; i++){
                        /*Assume that all parameters are in string data type for this situation
                                 * All other premetive data types are accepted.
                                */
                        String itemid = mod.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
                        String itemname = mod.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                                String price = mod.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
                                String quantity = mod.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();

                        cH = (y+70) + (10*i);                             //shifting drawing line

                        g2d.drawString(itemid, 0, cH);
                        g2d.drawString(itemname,50, cH);
                        g2d.drawString(price , 100, cH);
                                g2d.drawString(quantity , 150, cH);

                    }

                    /*Footer*/
                    font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,16) ;                  //changed font size
                    g2d.setFont(font);
                        g2d.drawString("Thank You Come Again",30, cH+10);
                                                                                 //end of the reciept
            }
            catch(Exception r){
              r.printStackTrace();
            }

                    result = PAGE_EXISTS;    
                }    
                return result;    
      }
   }

}
/*
 ################# THIS IS HOW TO USE THIS CLASS #######################

 Printsupport ps=new Printsupport();
 Object printitem [][]=ps.getTableData(jTable);
 ps.setItems(printitem);

 PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
 pj.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(),ps.getPageFormat(pj));
       try {
            pj.print();

            }
        catch (PrinterException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
 ################## JOIN TO SHARE KNOWLADGE ###########################

 */
```

Sometimes there arise a conflict between Java API with the printer driver. I solve it by deleting all the default paper templates in driver interface.